# Not able to open the deck UI for spinnaker

Tags: spinnaker

I installed spinnaker using the command

```
bash <(curl --silent https://spinnaker.bintray.com/scripts/InstallSpinnaker.sh)
```

on a local ubuntu machine.

After installation I am not able to connect to the Deck UI of spinnaker using URL: `http://localhost:9000`

Answer (score 0):

Check logs in /var/log/apache2 for errors, and /etc/apache2/ports.conf to see if it is is listening on 127.0.0.1:9000

The install script should have made those changes for you, but maybe you had a permissions issue or some other kind of local system policy preventing the installation from working properly.